# Use of calling javascript from java and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, java

I am learning  java 8  [Nashorn Javascript engine](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_nashorn_java_script.htm). But i am not getting what is the practical useof it. Here are my specific
questions

**Calling JavaScript from Java**

1) What is the practical scenario when as a developer i would like to call javascript from java ?

**Calling Java from Javascript**

2) What is the practical scenario when as a developer i would like to call java from javascript ?

3) If yes, How browser will execute java from javascript. Does system hosting needs to have JRE and browser will use that ?

Comment: Question 3 shows a great deal of misunderstanding. Nashorn is unrelated to a browser. And Javascript (in a browser) could (historically) make calls into Applets (but Applets are largely extinct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) What is the practical scenario when as a developer i would like to call javascript from java ?

1. Suppose that you're writing a browser in Java then you'll need to run JS interpreter from Java to display the page and handle JS code.
2. Suppose you want to provide a JS syntax checker in Java for example like JS editors in eclipse.
3. Or you want to run a tutorial website of JS where users write JS code in Browser and you evaluate it and show errors like it's done by most of the sites like Learnstreet, Udacity.
4. As a back end (server side) developer you have to provide a functionality to you front end (client side) developer where they can send you JS code and you do stuff with it on server. [Service Now](http://www.servicenow.com/) and [Presto Mashups](http://mdc.jackbe.com/prestodocs/v3.0/presto-dev/devIntro.html) are a few examples where it's done.
5. There is a JS API that you want to use without having to convert it to Java code first. It's common pattern to support your JS library for Java and several other languages now, so that they can be run with JS engines like [Mozilla Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) and [Oracle Nashorn](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html) without much hasstle.

> 2) What is the practical scenario when as a developer i would like to call java from javascript ?

1. You'll have entire Java API at your finger tips while writing JS code, answer is why not?
2. You're running some JS code on the Server using JS engine and you need to communicate output back to JVM or invoke some event. May be even listing directories, reading files calling database is the requirement from JS code.
3. Consider [Node JS](https://nodejs.org/en/), it's just a JS interpreter [written in C, C++](https://github.com/nodejs/node) It's doing the same thing. It's providing power of C and C++ to a JS developer. Same is done with the Rhino and Nashorn. By it's nature JS has a limited functionality as its used to run on brower, it needs some additional APIs to get a power boost. I took the example of Node JS as it's popularity shows just how much this power up was needed. Just for fun try this video [interview Ryan Dahl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAc0vQCC6UQ).

> 3) If yes, How browser will execute java from javascript. Does system hosting needs to have JRE and browser will use that ?

1. Browser will not run JS code containing Java parts. JS engines are meant to get the JS code on server side. This gives a JS developer an opportunity to use his JS skills to write server side code. However if needed browser can send the JS code to server for interpretation as in case of Presto Jackbe Mashups.

Comment: But `Node JS` is mainly about executing the javascript on server side. We don't call java code from javascript in `nodejs` right ?

Comment: Yes, it's just an example that JS code is calling C,C++ routines in Node JS. Same thing is done by Nashorn when it calls Java API from JS code.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with calling java from Javascript. However I have seen Javascript being called from Java. The use case I have seen is where a Java framework needed to be extended by end clients. This was achieved by letting the end clients add logic in Javascript. The actual Javascript code could then be stored in the database and executed when required by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

1) A practical use of a JavaScript engine in Java would be when creating or using an HTTP Adapter. In this case, you would need to be able to handle all javascript, to simulate a real browser connection. An example of a Java HTTP Adapter that deals with JavaScript is [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

2) I do not believe this is used very often, or at all, especially with the disapproval of the NPAPI plugin by Chrome and, in the future, Firefox ([source](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/)). Despite these points, communicating between javascript and java could be used to add functionality to a website or application, although this does not seem feasible.

3) See above.